# Something like Global.asax, but for Area

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, global-asax, asp.net-mvc-areas

**Situation:**

The method `Application_Start()` in the `Global.asax` loading a default configuration file that defines how the View will look in the default settings.

In the Areas I have customers who may have modified configuration file and if file doesn't exists the settings will be loaded from the default configuration file.

Right now is a modified configuration file if exists loaded in `BaseController` located in each Area.

But I don't like it in this way because every request loading the configuration file again.

**Question:**

Is there something like `Global.asax`, but for the Area, or something like `Area_Start()`?

Comment: What kind of configuration you have in your mind?

Comment: Your question is a little too generic and hence other users are having a hard time understanding what you want. You should provide some more information and perhaps a small description of what all you have tried so far.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, I changed the description.

Answer (score 0):

How about defining **_viewstart cshtml** for your Areas views?

Or having **global action filter** defined where u can find area name like this

[Getting area, controller and action names inside filter attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28391576/getting-area-controller-and-action-names-inside-filter-attributes)

and there you can  have custom code 
that will do the thing for you?